# Recursive method fill array php laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, recursion

I'm trying to create a recursive method to fill an array with each new item found.

```
function getUserUbigeoString($ubigeo_id){
    $ubigeoRepository = new \App\Repositories\UbigeoRepository();
    $ubigeos = array();

    $ubigeo = $ubigeoRepository->getUbigeo($ubigeo_id);

    if(!empty($ubigeo)){
        if($ubigeo->ubigeo_id == null){
            $ubigeos[] = $ubigeo->name;
        }

        $ubigeos[] = getUserUbigeoString($ubigeo->ubigeo_id);
    }

    return $ubigeos;
}
```

The objective of the code is to get an array fill with all the name of the ubigeos.

```
0 => ubigeo1
1 => ubigeo2
2 => ubigeo3
etc...
```

As of right now, i have tried placing the return many different locations, but the closest result i have gotten was:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      0 => "Port Dusty"
      1 => []
    ]
  ]
]
```

==========EDIT============
Structure of database ubigeos:

```
id  name     level ubigeo_id
----------------------------
3    ubigeo1  1     null
37   ubigeo2  2     3
55   ubigeo3  3     37
```

the output would be a simple array like so, which then i could implode into a comma separated string:

```
array:1 [
  0 => 'ubigeo1'
  1 => 'ubigeo2'
  2 => 'ubigeo3'
]
```

Comment: Can you give an example array and desired output. So it can be more understandable what you want to do

Comment: yes, i updates the answer with an example, its a simple array with the values, so i can use implode later on to get a comma separated string, thanks

Comment: Could you please add a description how the input is structured? I.e. do you just have a chain of Ubigeo entities where each ubigeo can have 0 or 1 reference to child Ubigeo (and the ubigeo.ubigeo_id defines this child entity)?

Comment: From where are you calling this function `getUserUbigeoString()`

Comment: sorry, added the database structure, hopefully it helps

Comment: @AmanRawat i'm calling it from my controller, this function is a helper, where i'm passing it the ubigeo_id = 55, so it get everything recursively from the bottom and get the output array

Comment: Could you offer a *worded description* of what you are trying to achieve withis this block in your code:  `if(!empty($ubigeo)){ //...}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so assuming that you really want to call this with function with an Ubigeo instance and only get the names from that and from the parent Ubigeo instances (i.e. calling the function with id 55 initially to get the result array), you can try something like this (I didn't want to modify your function call parameters - normally I would include the array as a function parameter instead of instantiating new one in each recursion step):

```
function getUserUbigeoString($ubigeo_id)
{
    $ubigeoRepository = new \App\Repositories\UbigeoRepository();
    $ubigeos = array();

    $ubigeo = $ubigeoRepository->getUbigeo($ubigeo_id);

    if(!empty($ubigeo))
    {
        if($ubigeo->ubigeo_id != null) {
            $ubigeos = getUserUbigeoString($ubigeo->ubigeo_id);
        }
        $ubigeos[] = $ubigeo->name;
    }

    return $ubigeos;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i needed. You're right, it would be better to pass the array as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Use Can do it with [lists](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries) method in laravel

Ex :

```
$ubigeoRepository->lists('ubigeo_id','id')->all();
```